# In Wordpress dashboard, how can I make specific user role post only in specific post category?

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a custom post type and also custom taxonomy for it, lets call it cpt-category for simplicity. I have 3 cpt-categories for this cpt.

Now, I have some custom user roles in dashboard - but I don't need to, I can just make custom capabilities for Subscriber role with User Role Editor.

But what I need is to make sure that Subscribers can only create new cpt's in **one specific** cpt-category out of three. So that the cpt-category would be set automatically if Subscriber creates a new cpt.

On the other hand, Admins should be able to choose from all three cpt-categories.

Is there a wp function for this?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subscriber role, by default, cannot edit or create posts. That said, there's no way to limit the categories that someone with the `edit_posts` capability has access to.

The easiest way to solve this issue would be to create a form in your front-end, that sends back to `admin-post.php` using the `admin_post` hook (for logged in users), and then doing your logic within the function for that hook.

Something very basic may look like this:

```
function create_cpt_post_subscriber() {
    if (!current_user_can('edit_post')) {
        return false;
    }

    /* do stuff */
}
add_action('admin_post_action_name', 'create_cpt_post_subscriber');
```

You would then use `wp_insert_post` within that function to create the new post using the `$_POST` parameters sent to `admin_post`. Within that hook, you have full access to $_POST as well.

Using AJAX will prevent your Subscribers from getting sent to the 'admin-post.php' page directly, so I'd advise using AJAX to submit the form.

Using `wp_insert_post`, you'd be able to program in the exact category ID you want them to use. If that category ID changed, though, you'd have to update it in the code as well, unless you used `get_term` to retrieve it by slug (advisable).

You can learn more about `wp_insert_post` [in the WordPress Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) and there's a tutorial for forms using `admin_post` hooks on [SitePoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/handling-post-requests-the-wordpress-way/).

Comment: OK, thank you very much for your help. I don't really have to use Subscriber, I can also use Editor. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Either way you'll need to have a front-end to force the category, there's no way within WordPress to limit categories by user role, any user role that has the edit_posts capability will have access to all categories.

Comment: Got it. I'll make something like a front-end dashboard for those users, create some acf form and force category. No problem. Thank you :)